# Table RelationShips in NoSQL

Tags: nosql

I am trying to shift from mysql to nosql.
Currently I have 2 tables in my database. File and Directory.

The fields in my File Table are {FileID, FileName, ParentDirID, FileAttributes}
The fields in my Directory Table are {DirID, DirName, ParentDirID, FileAttributes}

If I use any NoSQL DB (Mongo/Couch/AmazonSimpleDB) would I have to maintain two similar structures File and Directory or there would be something different.

Also I read that you can use Json to do insert in nosql db.

So is the following insertion possible where I can add a directory and the files in it using on single json

```
{dirid:"101",
dirName:"C",
ParentID:"100",
Files:{
[FileID:"201",
FileName:"a.txt"],
[FileID:"202",
FileName:"b.txt"]
}
}
```

If yes then how to create a query for update,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from relational (MySQL) to NoSQL requires some quick background.

In the relational world we want to normalize our data. The goal is to have data exist in only one place. This forces us to make quite a few tables to represent data.

In the NoSQL world (or at least some parts of it), the key word is denormalization. This means it's now ok to have the same data in different parts of the database. For example, we might store the user name in 10 different structures. If you want to change the user name, you'll have to go to 10 places and change it (potentially).

For the above reasons, quite a few NoSQL solutions do not support joins in the relational sense. Instead of storing structures separately and then joining, you store everything together.

For your specific use case, it seems you've already stumbled upon that idea. You have a directory document and then embed all file information into that document.

Some quick advice on how to denormalize data with NoSQL ... if you have embedded objects that are changing a lot, store just a reference to them and separate the objects. Otherwise you'll end up embedding them all over and real time updates become next to impossible.

Comment: Thanks ryan. Actually I am a bit confused. Since I have a file table and a directory table quite separate and a small relation like parent id. Would it make sense for me to move to NoSQL.

Comment: Yeah it might not make sense to move to NoSQL. You can still store file and directory separately in NoSQL and then join them somewhere. For example, in Mongo you can store each in different collections. Then you can "join" them at different points. You could join them via map/reduce in Mongo, via your application code, on the front end (assuming a web application) with AJAX calls. But writing an adhoc query the way you would with MySQL ... that wouldn't be possible if you kept them separate. Generally with NoSQL you'd want to put them together in one object. Hope that helps?